# How can I solve " Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value" Exception in Laravel 7?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm quite new to Laravel, I would like to update a column in mySQL database named "client_id" the name of the table is "projects" I would like to insert this column when a Client creates a new Project, because the project belongs to the Client who created it. "client_id" is the Primary Key (id) in the table called "clients". There is a relationship between "clients" table and "projects" table. I have written some code to solve this problem but I'm getting this Exception and the "client_id" column is not updated.
Please help.
[image]

[image]

Store Method in my Controller:

```
/**
     * Store a newly created Project in storage.
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name'                  => 'required|string|max:255',
            'description'           => 'required|string|max:255',
            'start_date'            => 'required|date',
            'start_time'            => 'required|string|max:10',
        ]);

        $project = Project::create([
                    'name'              => $request->name,
                    'description'       => $request->description,
                    'start_date'        => $request->start_date,
                    'start_time'        => $request->start_time,
        ]);

        
        
        $loggedinId = Auth::id();
        $project->update(['created_by' => $loggedinId]);

        $userId = $loggedinId;
        
        $clientId = Client::where('user_id', '=', $userId)->pluck('id')->all();

        DB::table('projects')->where('created_by', '=', $loggedinId)->update([ 'client_id' => $clientId]);
        
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'You have successfully submitted your Job Card');

    }
```

Relationship in my Client Model:

```
/**
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
    }
```

Relationship in my Project Model:

```
/**
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class, 'client_id');
    }
```

Form In my Blade View:

```
      <form method="POST" action="{{ route('client-jobcard.store') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <label for="name">{{ __('Job Card Name') }}</label><span class="required">*</span>
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <label for="description">{{ __('Job Card Description') }}</label><span class="required">*</span>
                                <textarea class="form-control{{ $errors->has('description') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="description" rows="4" style="height: 150px;" name="description" value="{{ old('description') }}" required autofocus></textarea>
                                @if ($errors->has('description'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('description') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="start_date">Start Date</label><span class="required">*</span>
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="start_date"  name="start_date" value="{{ old('start_date') }}" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="submission_date">Start Time</label><span class="required">*</span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="start_time"  name="start_time" value="{{ old('start_time') }}" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        {{ __('Submit') }}
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>   
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
$clientId = Client::where('user_id', '=', $userId)->pluck('id')->all();
```

will return a *column*, not the single ID ("2") that you want.

Then, when you assign it to `client_id` which is an integer, the ORM will render it as the string `[2]` instead of the number `2`, and that will give you an error.

Either retrieve just the *first* tuple from `Client`, or extract `$clientId[0]` manually (wasteful and **not** recommended).

**You also have a second error** I had overlooked:

```
'created_by', '=', $loggedinId
```

The above means that `created_by` must be an integer value, but the text of the error implies SQL expects it to be a *datetime*. You seem to have a wrong definition in the database.

Comment: thank you for your response, "retrieve first tuple" means retrieving using ID? Like the way it is explained in documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Comment: Yes. Basically, **if you're sure the query will return something**, you can just use `->first()` instead of `->all()`. I suspect you'd better experiment a bit to develop familiarity with Eloquent.

Comment: I noticed now that the error was a bit more complicated. Added to answer.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. Changing from `->all()` to `->first()` has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

your time field is in string , it has to be changed , it is not the same format
can you try this instead

Comment: thanks for your response, I had tried to use time data type instead of String and I was getting the same error. I decided to change to String for now. But I also got challenges with Validating the time field.